# Replace strings with different parameters stored elsewhere

Tags: php, oop

### Issue solved. Thanks to @trincot

EDIT: To clear things up. I want to REPLACE a string, lets say %www% with another one I've got stored in another file. So when I for example write link href="%www%/pub/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet", %www% will echo the URL that I stored someplace else. The problem I'm facing with my code down below is that it doesn't work - and I can't see why not.

---

I *simply* want to replace %www% (and other stuff) in my files with a parameter already defined somewhere else (like the configuration).

Currently I'm using

```
class Template {
    private $params = Array();

    function Write($str) {
        echo $str;
    }
    function FilterParams($str){
        foreach ($this->params as $param => $value) {
            if (is_object($value)) {
                continue;
            }

            $str = str_ireplace('%' . $param . '%', $value, $str);
        }

        return $str;
    }
    function SetParam($param, $value) {
        $this->params[$param] = $value;
    }
}
```

And I'm calling my code and setting my parameters in my global file

```
// Initiate classes
$template = new Template();

// Parameters
$template->SetParam('www', "google.com");
```

Now I'd preferably want the %www% on my login to actually display google.com and not %www%. I uhm... 'borrowed' this from a CMS I've gotten from somewhere and believe this is all the code. I've tried to search for a solution here on stackoverflow and google, but never found a sufficient answer.

The answer is probably dead in front of my face, but you know how it is.
Apologies if this is already answered, but I have no clue what to search for to find a proper answer.

Comment: What's the problem?  There is no question.

Comment: Maybe you are using `Write()` on the string, forgetting to call `FilterParams()`? 
If this is the case, then either do `$template->Write(FilterParams($str))`, or change the implementation of `Write()` to `echo $this->FilterParams($str);`

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sorry if that's unclear. The code doesn't work. That's the problem. :P

Comment: @Landen I'm trying to replace %www% in, let's say <link href="%www%/pub/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"> to display my url so it's not static, and can be easily changed.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Will have a looksie. Edit: Nope. No sigar.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it throw an error? Is the output something you didn't expect?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser Again: Sorry. It doesn't do anything. No error, no nothing.

Comment: Show us the code where you call `FilterParams`. Without that, there is little we can do for you. The piece you posted, just works: [eval.in](https://eval.in/516657)

Comment: @trincot I'm an idiot. The code I'm using requires a tpl system to be used and it's 'scanning' the entire file before 'posting' it. I'm not doing this at all. I will sit down and rewrite my entire system. This was such an idiotic move. Thanks! :P